# How to check if column values contain any of array elements in clickhouse?

Tags: sql, database, clickhouse

Let's say we have a table with column "titles" like this:

| title |
| --- |
| The Colour of Magic |
| The Light Fantastic |
| Equal Rites |
| Wyrd Sisters |
| Reaper Man |

and filtering words like this

```
filter_words = ['Man', 'Sisters']
```

The main idea I came up to is to convert `filter_words` from array to table like this

```
select arrayJoin(['Man', 'Sisters']) as filter_word
```

and join on some condition. I've tried this condition but got an exception that condition is not supported. what is the correct way to filter column by string part?

```
JOIN filter_words
    ON position(not_filtered.title, filter_words.filter_word) > 0
```

```
JOIN filter_words
    ON '%' + filter_words.filter_word + '%' like not_filtered.title
```

Answer (score 0):

You may split the initial string to array of tokens and use a handy [hasAny](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-functions#hasany) function to check if two arrays have intersection by some elements.

```
WITH ['Man', 'Sisters'] AS filter_words
SELECT title
FROM VALUES 
(
  'title String'
, 'The Colour of Magic'
, 'The Light Fantastic'
, 'Equal Rites'
, 'Wyrd Sisters'
, 'Reaper Man'
) t
WHERE hasAny(splitByWhitespace(t.title), filter_words)
```

The result is:

| title |
| --- |
| Wyrd Sisters |
| Reaper Man |